# PHP - How to get the http part from a string

Tags: php

This is my var_dump();

```
string(244) "a:3:{s:3:"url";s:81:"http://rsl.local/wp-content/uploads/wp-user-manager-uploads/2018/03/time-icon.png";s:4:"path";s:101:"/Users/aaronsummers/Sites/rsl-awards/wp-content/uploads/wp-user-manager-uploads/2018/03/time-icon.png";s:4:"size";i:1342;}"
```

How can i grab the url section?
`"http://rsl.local/wp-content/uploads/wp-user-manager-uploads/2018/03/time-icon.png"` (without the quotes)

Comment: What part exactly?

Comment: Im trying to get the image url which is: http://rsl.local/wp-content/uploads/wp-user-manager-uploads/2018/03/time-icon.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a serialized string. Just unserialize it, and then dereference the 'url' key:

```
$url = unserialize($str)['url'];
```

Comment: This is a revelation, thanks. I've not come across unserialize before.

Comment: I was watching the post, you answered 5 seconds before @ChristianM

Answer (score 5):

This is a serialized PHP array, so a simple `unserialize` on that string should give you an array back on which you can just access the url key:

```
$array = unserialize($yourString);
echo $array['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'd not used unserialize before, unfortunately Alex pipped you to the post by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP `unserialize` to get the url.

`$url = unserialize($str);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php